# SqueakMap won't work in a fresh 3.10 dev image

Tags: squeak

I just downloaded a fresh Squeak-dev image from Damien Cassou, clicked on SqueakMap, and got the error that in SqueakMap>>categories, the objects instance variable is nil, but shouldn't be. I can't be the only one with that error, am I? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixes it:

```
SMSqueakMap default loadUpdates
```

Easy, huh?